# Looking for a way to make parameters optional if a requirement is met - C#

Tags: c#

As the title states, I'm looking to make parameters in a function optional but only if a parameter inputted into the same function is true.

```
//if bool required is true.
public Foo(bool required, string optional = optional, ..., string optional = optional)

//if bool required is false.
public Foo(bool required, string required, ..., string required)
```

Sorry I'm really quite new to coding and don't really know how to phrase this where I will get something useful from Google.

But is this at all possible any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What's the use case? What does Foo do?

Comment: Why can't you determine the `boolean` before calling the method and choose the appropriate overload?

Comment: Hi so I'm trying to do a character generation function where the required bool specifies if its 'random' or not obviously if it is random then I don't want to have to enter in a whole load over aditional values id rather it just be `public Foo(true)` and then the function runs

Comment: You wont be able to simply not send parameters, even though they they might not be needed, your method signature will require them. You might be able to fidget around this by using argument/parameters defaults, but the requirement remains.

Comment: This sounds like you need two methods `FooRandom()` and `FooNotRandom(string required, ..., string required)`  Then just do `if(requried) FooRandom(); else FooNotRandom();`

Comment: Sounds like you need two methods: `GenerateRandomCharacter()` and `GenerateCharacter(<some additional values here>)`.

Comment: @mxmissile So would I need to just specify that the param is equal to something within the definition of the method (definition is probably wrong word but I hope you understand) like under the if bool required is true? sorry thats probably jargon to someone who is actually able to code correctly.

Comment: See ps2goat's answer below, he explains it well.

Comment: It sounds like you need `Foo(AttributePack)` and call it either with `Foo(new AttributePack { str = 20, dex = 11, int = 4, cha = 22 })` or `Foo(RollRandomAttributes())`

Comment: @mason Makes perfect sense actually. I'll just do that no point in trying to overcomplicate things. I was just trying to reduce how much code I needed to write lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to decide whether an argument is optional by the values of other arguments then you'll need to do it via simple `if`-clause.

```
public void Foo(bool required, string a = null)
{
    if (required && string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Parameter a is required");
    }

    // do something
}
```

Comment: Ah right, this makes more sense, I'll be honest I didn't really know that I could create errors myself (obviously I knew it must be a thing but didn't know how.
` public void Foo(bool required, string a = null, string b = null)
{
    if (required && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(b))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Parameter" //not sure how to identify which string is the issue"is required");
    }

    // do something
}
`
would something like that work?

Comment: sorry I dont know why the things isnt doing that in code....

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through overloading, but my recommended pattern for clarity has been to use different function names. This is especially useful in your case, where your parameter types match between the different methods.

```cs
FooOptional(string optional1 = null, string optional2 = null) // ...
FooRequired(string required1, string required2) // ....
```

And then you can have an internal method like:

```cs
private void _fooInternal(string param1, string param1) // ...
```

As long as the parameter count and types match, your public methods can call this internal one.

```cs
public void FooOptional(string optional1 = null, string optional2 = null) {
    _fooInternal(optional1, optional2);
}
public void FooRequired(string required1, string required2) {
    _fooInternal(required1, required2);
}
```

If you need to pass along a boolean (e.g., `isRequired`), add that to your internal function as a parameter, and your public methods can just pass in `true` or `false`.

Comment: You *can't* do this through overloading.  In C++, if the first parameter is *always* known at compile-time, you could use template specialization.  But C# generics do not have non-type template arguments.  And you can't do it with a parameter value AT ALL, because overloading and defaulted arguments have to be figured out at compile time, but parameter values can change at runtime.

Comment: You can do it through overloading if the parameters are different enough. In this case, they are not. You would need at least one required parameter of a different type. What people usually do is `Foo(optional, optional, etc)` and `Foo(required, optional, etc.)`. So the boolean would only be passed in one case. I wasn't saying the specific example given by the OP would work without adjustment.

Comment: You're right though, the function signatures would have to be able to be differentiated by the compiler, there were just a lot of combinations to go through that I didn't feel the need to dig in that much at the moment.